# Pseudonyms in SugarCRM

Tags: php, crm, sugarcrm

I'm creating a membership database for a political organization using SugarCRM and there's one requirement I don't know how to handle.

Every member of the organization is allowed to use a pseudonym, and in those cases, their real full names, along with some other fields is a secret and should only be viewed and edited by an administrator.

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the default first_name, last_name fields in the Contacts module as the name or pseudonym. Then create a couple of custom fields for the real first/last name which would be used only if a pseudonym. You'll need to customize view.edit.php and view.detail.php (custom/modules/Contacts/views) to show the real name fields if the current user is an admin.